# mongo use $add aggregation within an aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm trying to add 1 day within an equality aggregation so the day+1 should be compared to the field modifiedAt which contains an ISODATE in my DB.

Unfortunately I'm unable to do this.
error within mongodb compass is 'Field must not begin with $ or . field path was $add'

---

```
{"$match":
   {"$expr":
    {
      "$eq":["$modified",{"$add": [ISODate('xxx'),1*24*60*60000]}]}
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use `ISODate()` on a value which is already a `Date`? You don't need to convert a `Date` value into a `Date`. Add the day value directly.

Comment: Field `modifiedAt` or `modified`?

Comment: Field: modifiedAt

Comment: Why do you query on `modified`?

Comment: I'm matching two dates : modified and an (ISODate + 1 day) which is the next day.

Comment: Please provide some sample documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to work as expected:

```
mongos> db.f.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60038464a2d94094f8a216bc"), "modified" : ISODate("2021-01-17T00:27:16.280Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6003853ca2d94094f8a216bd"), "modified" : ISODate("2021-01-17T02:27:16.280Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60038544a2d94094f8a216be"), "modified" : ISODate("2021-01-16T02:27:16.280Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6003855fa2d94094f8a216bf"), "modified" : ISODate("2021-01-18T02:27:16.280Z") }
mongos> db.f.aggregate( [  {"$match":  {"$expr":  { "$eq":["$modified",{"$add": [ISODate("2021-01-17T02:27:16.280Z"),1*24*60*60000]}]}    } } ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6003855fa2d94094f8a216bf"), "modified" : ISODate("2021-01-18T02:27:16.280Z") }
mongos>
```

Comment: This still doesnt work for me, check the error message above

Comment: the command is a$match and the only variables is the ISODATE which is ISODate('2020-01-14T10:27:04.669+00:00')

Comment: i had to update my compass to the newest version seems to old version could not compute some of the commands

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my Compass to a new version